# Can I use a company's logo on the merch I want to advertise to them?

Tags: copyright, trademark, fair-use, commerce, branding

I am a merchandise designer.

I want to advertise conceptualized apparel/general merch designs to a company by email with the option for them to purchase it.
I want to use their current brand ie. *logo mark, logo type, tagline,colors, company's background* etc in the designs I'm email advertising to them.

Is this legally covered under advertising/trademark laws? Is the company's permission required?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is covered under both trademark and copyright law.

Yes, you need permission and you will probably need to pay for that if they allow it.

Comment: Im not understanding your answer; are you saying this type of advertisement is covered under trademark laws or not covered? Also you said I need their permission and will probably have to pay for it. I think you misunderstood the question. I want to advertise to only the same company in which I want to use their logo. Sort of like a in-house third party designer. Why would I need to pay them for suggestive designs?

Comment: Because you are using their IP in a way that is not fair use.

Comment: @MerchDesignerUS offer to make them a mock up or test piece, but not make any yet, then their "go ahead, show us" can be read as a license to make such a sample with their branding.